# Can we see the source code for PowerShell cmdlets?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm learning some PowerShell. Is it possible to see the source code for a built-in cmdlet like [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)?

Comment: You can now - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/HEAD/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/GetChildrenCommand.cs.

Answer (score 36):

[The source for Powershell is now available on Github.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell)
The source for `Get-ChildItem` can be found [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c1faf1e6e10fc1ce45e84ef6f49ae7136c67a111/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/GetChildrenCommand.cs).

Answer (score 23):

Actually, your best bet is to go check out [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx). This open source software community project is "aimed at providing a widely useful set of additional cmdlets...". The developers on the project are PowerShell MVPs and know their stuff.

As far as using reflection on the existing PowerShell cmdlets, PowerShell MVP Oisin Grehan made a handy function titled "[Reflect-Cmdlet](https://web.archive.org/web/20190521090145/https://www.nivot.org/post/2008/10/30/ATrickToJumpDirectlyToACmdletsImplementationInReflector)". I won't steal his code and place it here, but basically what you do is:

```
Get-Command Get-ChildItem | Reflect-Cmdlet
```

And then [.NET Reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) pops up with the right assembly opened up and expanded and everything. It's really pretty cool.

Comment: +1 for the link to `Reflect-Cmdlet`, it was very helpful. Modified to make it work with Jetbrains DotPeek. https://gist.github.com/dennisroche/013c5a56d9a7f16851cb

Comment: That cmd-let has an invalid SSL certificate. This also appears to be [possibly without using any third-party tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32189485/542251)

Answer (score 17):

For **compiled** Cmdlets, you can get the path to the `.dll` with:

```
(Get-Command Get-ChildItem).DLL
```

(Replace `Get-ChildItem` with the cmdlet you are interested in)

**Example:**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-Command Get-StoragePool).DLL

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Once you know the path to the `.dll`, you can open it with a .NET disassembler like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/):

```
& dotPeek64.exe (Get-Command Get-ChildItem).DLL
```

Comment: Fascinating, this doesn't seem to work in PowerShell 7.0 with the DnsClient module, for example. Also, `Get-Module DnsClient|Get-Member` shows no DLL property/member.

Comment: @0xC0000022L `(get-module dnsclient).Path` gives you the PSD1 file, in which you'll see `NestedModules` references `dnslookup`, a DLL under the same directory.

Answer (score 14):

I think if you were just starting PowerShell, this is what you'd be looking for:

```
$metadata = New-Object system.management.automation.commandmetadata (Get-Command Get-Process)
[System.management.automation.proxycommand]::Create($MetaData) | out-file C:\powershell\get-process.ps1
```

This will create a script which shows how [Get-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx) runs. Put in any cmdlet you want to replace Get-Process. If you want to google more about it, this is how you would create a proxy function.

Comment: Nice and simple, no need for Reflector.NET or DotPeek, cheers.  By the way, `[System.management.automation.proxycommand]::Create($MetaData)` seems sufficient for me, to just display the results on screen.

Comment: This creates a [proxy command](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/04/extending-and-or-modifing-commands-with-proxies.aspx), which isn't the same thing as looking at the source code at all. This doesn't give you the source code for Get-Process, or show you how it runs; it returns a base script that you could use to modify the cmdlet, for example, by adding additional parameters to it.

Answer (score 3):

You might also like to take a look at [Windows Installer PowerShell Snap-In](http://psmsi.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. It's a smaller project than the community extensions, so it is easier to get your head around what's going on.

Check out *Professional Windows PowerShell Programming: Snapins, Cmdlets, Hosts and Providers* (Wrox Professional Guides), ISBN: 0470173939 - it's one of the most useful books I've found for writing cmdlets and providers.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) to "see" the source code. You need to know the assembly though, but it should also accessible using the GetType method or similar.

This [PowerShellLanguage .NET Reflector Add-In](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins/Wiki/View.aspx?title=PowerShellLanguage&referringTitle=Home) can perhaps be useful.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell cmdlets' assemblies are located in GAC. You can find "Get-ChildItem" cmdlet in:

**Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management assembly, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand** class.

I've used ILSpy .NET decompiler and filtered GAC assemblies by "powershell" string. As I understand, **Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.*** assemblies contain built-in cmdlets.

Answer (score 1):

For some cmdlets that are installed with `Install-Module` and contain source code and not binaries, (e.g. PSnmap):

```
Install-Module -Name PSnmap
```

...you can view their code by looking at the `Definition` property from:

```
Get-Command Invoke-PSnmap | Format-List
```

If not, most likely, you will need to decompile some binary (e.g. the file specified in the `DLL` property).

Answer (score 0):

Some code can be found on the Reference Resource Site:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management.Automation/System/Management/Automation/ChildItemCmdletProviderIntrinsics.cs,c6eed9f6a5417c19

This only gives the outline though; not the code's detail.

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe that the source code for PowerShell has ever been released.

Comment: There is more open source code (now) than people might imagine: [Windows PowerShell blog: The Archive module is now open-source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/04/25/the-archive-module-is-now-open-source/).

Comment: @codekaizen [Powershell is now open source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).

Comment: Totally outdated answer.