# Programmatically determine if Windows 8 secure boot is enabled

Tags: c#, .net, security, winapi, windows-8

I'm writing a security application which validates many security rules and policies on user machines. I need to implement a test method that returns true when [Windows 8's Secure Boot feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824987.aspx) is enabled, or false when it disabled.

I searched for information and I saw that this is a BIOS feature. So my question is: is it possible to get the status of Windows 8 Secure Boot using C# code? If yes, how?

[image: Secure Boot from BIOS]

---

Update:
See the answer of @magicandre1981, It's important to mention that the state registry key exists only when secure boot feature is supported. If you're not finding this key on your machine, probably your machine doesn't support secure boot.

to check secure boot status / support go to run - > msinfo32.exe and search for  "Secure Boot State"

Comment: I think you'll end up P/Invoking [`GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj204593(v=vs.85).aspx), but I've not tried it myself so unable to provide more of a steer or an actual tested answer.

Comment: There's a [Confirm-SecureBootUEFI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603041.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet. You can [decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266250/can-we-see-the-source-code-for-powershell-cmdlets) cmdlets to see which Windows / .NET API's it calls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MSinfo32.exe` read the value `UEFISecureBootEnabled` from the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecureBoot\State`.

[image]

On my system `SecureBoot` is disabled and return value is 0. So I assume that 1 means enabled.

Comment: I don`t have state key in my machine. Inside SecureBoot key i have "avaliable updates" and (defualt) keys. I change secure boot configuration in my bios and didn`t see any change.

Comment: there is a key State. Here you have the value. I'll insert a picture.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see it and you right. marked as answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I turned on secure boot through BIOS and now it 1 - exactly like you assumed

Comment: I test it on 2 more machines. the State key is not exists in every machine. I'm not sure why

Comment: what is msinfo32.exe telling you on those systems?

Comment: what fields do you want to know?

Comment: @Ofir the value if secure boot is enabled or not: http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-94-73-metablogapi/1411.image_5F00_0A7E7B6E.png http://blogs.technet.com/b/home_is_where_i_lay_my_head/archive/2013/09/18/enabling-secure-boot-in-windows-8.aspx

Comment: "Secure Boot State: Unsupported" Is there any way to check by code if a machine supports secure boot?

Comment: unsupported means the system has UEFI, but doesn't support secure boot. So it not there and acts like disabled.

Comment: I assuming that when secure boot is not supported the state key is not exists at all. when its disabled the state key value is 0

Comment: yes, I also think this. I only have a device with UEFI which supports Secure Boot. My older PC is still BIOS.

Comment: A colleague just told me that in Windows 10 Pro, modifications of the registry key are not put back after you change the SecureBoot setting in BIOS. On his machine the value was set to 1 (he says, he did not change it) and SecureBoot was off anyway ...

Answer (score 2):

Good code for Windows 10 too of course and should handle most conditions including legacy or missing key and exception, as well the future.. Prints to console whilst also returning the flag for batch or script use:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace CheckSecureBoot
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main()
        {
            int rc = 0;
            string key = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecureBoot\State";
            string subkey = @"UEFISecureBootEnabled";
            try
            {
                object value = Registry.GetValue(key, subkey, rc);
                if (value != null)
                    rc = (int)value;
            }
            catch { }
            Console.WriteLine($@"{subkey} is {(rc >= 1 ? "On" : "Off")} ({rc.ToString()})");
            return rc;
        }
    }
}
```