# Where to find the source code for the powershell cmdlets in the NetTCPIP module, specifically New-NetIPAddress?

Tags: c#, powershell, github, powershell-cmdlet

I have seen this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266250/can-we-see-the-source-code-for-powershell-cmdlets) and looked at the answers that say the source code is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).  However when I browse the source I can't find the [NetTCPIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) "module" or any of the cmdlets in it.  Searching GitHub for [New-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/new-netipaddress?view=windowsserver2022-ps) doesn't come up with anything either. I have seen some answers having to do with writing more powershell to reflect on the command you want, but I haven't been able to get any of it to work yet.  I am a C# programmer and I don't know powershell.  I'm really just trying to find the API to add an IP Address to an existing interface programmatically in C# without having to call powershell from C#, but I am going to post that as a separate question referring to this one.  For this question I'm specifically going at it by trying to determine what New-NetIPAddress is calling.

Comment: Try `(get-command new-netipaddress).Definition`, the cmdlet is a wrapper around CIM I believe

Comment: To add to Santiago's comment: specifically, these cmdlets are implemented in [CDXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/cdxml-overview).